# What algorithm to choose

Tags: algorithm

asked in a recent interview:

What data structure would you use to implement spell correction in a document. The goal is to find if a given word typed by the user is in the dictionary or not (no need to correct it). 
What is the complexity?

Comment: if the dictionary is read-only and is built at the initialization phase, and all you need is a yes/no search, why just a hash table or a binary tree or even a sorted array isn't enough? Of course the real spell checking is more complex than that, but given a simple question, the solution should not be more complex than required

Comment: I think the hash is the way to go.

Comment: Doesn't this depend on language? I'd start with a set-like container provided by the built-in libraries, then profile. For example in both C++ and Python this is called `set`, but it's a completely different data structure. I'm pretty sure both of them can perform lookups into a 1M word container faster than I can type, so profiling may well be the end of it.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a "Radix," or "Patricia," tree to index the dictionary. See here, including an example of its use to index dictionary words: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Radix_tree. There is a useful discussion at that link of its complexity.

Answer (score 3):

if I'm understanding the question correctly, you are given a dictionary (or a list of "correct" words), and are asked to specify whether an input word is in the dictionary.  So you're looking for data structures with very fast lookup times.  I would go with a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)

Comment: You'd use a set, not a hash table. You just need to check for inclusion in the set, you don't need to map the words to any values. A Trie would still be a better option that's more tailored to this particular problem.

Comment: @FogleBird: your terminology re sets etc. is appropriate to some domains (e.g. C++), but in general Comp Sci usage a "hash table" might have a "empty" value type... it's a trivial detail.

Comment: @Tony - I agree to some degree, but in practice I've seen too many people use hash tables with dummy values when a perfectly good set implementation is available and more appropriate.

Comment: most set implementations do just that... a hash table with a "dummy" value. not to mention that for spell *correction* you need the corrected version...

Answer (score 3):

I would use a [DAWG](http://www.pathcom.com/~vadco/dawg.html) (Directed Acyclic Word Graph) which is basically a compressed [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

These are commonly used in algorithms for Scrabble and other words games, like Boggle.

I've done this before. The TWL06 Scrabble dictionary with 170,000 words fits in a 700 KB structure both on disk and in RAM.

Answer (score 1):

The [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) tells you how many letters you need to change to get from one string to another ... by finding the one with less substitutions you are able to provide correct words (also see [Damerau Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance))

The increase performance you should not calculate the distance against your whole dictionary and constrain it with some heuristic, for instance words that start with same first letter.

Comment: Although the algorithm is used in spell checkers, it's not a data structure (which is what's being asked).

Comment: My bad, I understood wrongly the question. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Bloom Filter. False positives are possible, but false negatives are not. As you know the dictionary in advance you can eliminate the false negatives by using a perfect hash for your input.(dictionary). Or you can use this as an auxiliary data structure behind your actual dictionary data structure.

edit: Of course complexity is O(1) for bloom filter.